# (TeeChart - Java) Evaluation Version Performance Issues

Tags: java, performance, teechart

We have evaluated TeeChart for Java, and decided to use it. However, one issue concerns us and we need your help to clarify it. The issue is about performance of TeeChart Evaluation version. We have observed that TeeChart gets intolerablely slow when data size exceeds 128*1024 points in colorgrid and 3D surface plots (we have lots of data to render :) ). In addition, We have tried with different GPUs and result is almost same.

And we also observed that CPU usage never exceeds 10% in quad-core intel i7.

Our questions are:

- Does TeeChart limit the speed in evaluation version? :)
- How can we increase speed of TeeCharts besides the recommendations under "Speed" branch in demo app?
- Does evaluation version have all required libraries for GDI usage?
- Is it possible that Evaluation version does not use GDI or do we need to set it?

Basic specifications for our system:

OS: Windows XP SP3
RAM: 4 GB
JRE: version 1.6.0_26
TeeChart Current Evaluation version.

thanks in advance

Comment: I do not have any TeeChart experience, but if I'd be in this situation, I'd start challenging the vendor and maybe initiate a PoC based on the full version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeeChart doesn't add any speed limitation in the evaluation versions.

We've made some tests here with the ColorGrid and the Surface series with about 300.000 points and we think the response is acceptable. Find below the examples.

ColorGrid example:

```
    tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);

    ColorGrid colgrid1 = new ColorGrid(tChart1.getChart());
    colgrid1.fillSampleValues(500);
    colgrid1.getPen().setVisible(false);
```

Surface example:

```
    tChart1.getAspect().setOrthogonal(false);
    tChart1.getAspect().setZoom(70);
    tChart1.getAspect().setChart3DPercent(80);
    tChart1.getAxes().getDepth().setVisible(true);

    Surface surf1 = new Surface(tChart1.getChart());
    surf1.fillSampleValues(500);
    surf1.getPen().setVisible(false);
```

Could you please send us a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here? We'll be glad to take a look at it and try to suggest you a satisfying solution.

You can send it through this forums or mailing to "sales at steema dot com".

--

Best Regards,

Yeray Alonso

Steema Support Central